# Package held back by apt despite being marked install

Tags: apt

I have a machine running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with the kernel updated to 5.3.0. Awhile back I installed a particular version of wine from winehq and used `apt-mark` to fix it at that version. I now wish to undo that and let wine upgrade to the latest version. I ran:

```
apt-mark unhold wine-stable wine-amd64 wine-i386
```

That appeared to be successful, as `apt-mark showhold` now comes back empty (these were the only packages I was holding). However, the packages are still held back when I run `apt full-upgrade` or Software Updater.

As a cross-check, I also ran `dpkg --get-selections | grep wine` and it came back with:

```
wine-stable                 install
wine-stable-amd64           install
wine-stable-i386:i386       install
```

I also ran `dpkg --get-selections | grep hold` and it came back empty.

Does anybody know why this is happening and how I can fix it? I figure my next move will be to try forcing the new version, but even if that works I'm not sure it will remove the hold (plus, I would really like to know the root cause here, if I can).

Comment: Please add output of `apt-cache policy  wine-stable wine-amd64 wine-i386 wine-stable-amd64 wine-stable-i386:i386` to the question body by [editing it](https://askubuntu.com/q/1252384/66509).

Comment: I have the opposite problem.```apt-mark hold``` doesn't work for me.At first ```apt-mark showhold``` prints the package , but then I'm able to upgrade it via ```sudo apt install package``` ! Then ```apt-mark showhold``` shows nothing despite the fact that I haven't **unhold**ed it. Strange.

Comment: If you have solved your problem, please post the solution as an answer, instead of editing the question.

Comment: Done. I can't accept my own answer for 16 hours, apparently, so I'll try to remember to come back and do that later. And thanks to both of you for the polite etiquette tips. I probably ought to go look for the FAQ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. When I went to run apt-cache as requested in the comments, I discovered there was an old version of wine installed from the Ubuntu repositories in parallel to that from winehq. When I removed the old version, it removed my entire wine installation, so I reinstalled and now everything is working.

Not sure how the two got installed in parallel, but I'm not the only admin on the machine in question.